# Why the spotlight is working only in scene view window but not in game view?

Tags: unity, c#

[image: Spotlight]

What i did is disabled in the Hierarchy the Directional Light.
The Spotlight is child of the character so it will move with it.

Then in Window > Lighting > Settings

[image: Light]

In the Spotlight i just changed the range and rotation a bit.
It's strange since it's showing the light in the scene view but not in the game view not even when running the game.

And this is the Spotlight config:

[image: Spot]

Comment: Are you accessing/controlling the spotlight in any way using a script?

Comment: In the screenshots, the only problem is that your camera is not looking at the character and instead it's looking into the void.

Answer (score 1):

Found how to do it. In Window > Lighting > Setting: Skybox Material set it back to original: Default-Skybox then in Environment Lighting setting the color to black. Then in Environment Reflections: Intensity Multiplier set to 0 then in the Main Camera in the Inspector: Changing Clear Flags to SolidColor and changing the Back Ground color to black.

You can see all the settings in the next screenshot:

[image: Working light]